# R compare / flag / days difference / skip same transaction line

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a split analysis. I want to be able to use my unique identifier I created by merging two columns and identify transactions done by those accounts within 3 days of each other.

My issue is all transactions are 1 row each. When I use the following formula:

```
as.Date(dataframe$column) - as.Date(samedataframe$column)
```

For transaction dates. Naturally everything appears as 0 days difference since it's subtracting itself. Someone mentioned 'for' and 'next functions and I tried making an complicated code for that but R didn't like the ('s then it didn't like the $'s indicating the column.

Not sure if anyone else has tried to make the data recognize the same lines/unique account and then differentiate based on dates. I can see how it would cause other issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you are trying to do, but to illustrate, let's create a example data frame.

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(
    seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),
        by = "day", 
        length.out = 20),
    size = 30,
    replace = TRUE
  )
)

head(df)

  id       date
1  1 2019-01-07
2  1 2019-01-07
3  3 2019-01-19
4  1 2019-01-08
5  2 2019-01-12
6  3 2019-01-11
```

If this is the structure in your data, then you just have to group by id, arrange your data by date an do as follow.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(days_after = date - lag(date))
```

Comment: Hey Johan! I appreciate your reply. I realize I could improve my data set example. I followed your advice but it ended up turning my data into a tibble and although it ran without issue it didn't add a 'Days_After' column to my work. Apparently the enter key on my phone doesn't count to enter down in this paragraph. The column in my work with the date is called 'Tran_Date' and format is '2019-08-07' , the unique identifier is a character combination. It's a bit over a thousand rows of data. Not sure if any of that helps or not.

Comment: you have to overwrite the object `df` with the result of my code (put this in the first line `df <- `). It would be nice if you update your question with a little example of your data, select a few rows and keep the same columm names.

Comment: Figured it out tonight! I needed the df after the <- as well. You were a big help Johan and I liked your post. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Nice, we are here to help. Just remember to improve your questions in the future.  [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be useful for that.